# Cannot Insert Values into Table (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 6 column =

```
StudentID (INTEGER),
Name (VARCHAR),
Alamat (TEXT),
Gender (VARCHAR),
DateofBirth (DATE),
NoHp (VARCHAR);
```

This is Image for Details

[image]

And, When I insert values into this table, I get the error message.

This is image what error message

[image]

please help me,
Thank you.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: alter table & assign the length as now it is considering only 1 length data.

Comment: The size of Gender is `VARCHAR(7)` and the data you entered into that column is of length more then seven

Comment: verify the size of each column in the definition and the length of value provided for insertion.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you define "Laki-Laki" gender? :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to screenshot, you specified the `Gender` column as `varchar(7)` and you are trying to set a string which length is 9.(laki-laki)

I suggest you to **increase** the column length or be careful about the string lengths you want to set.

Comment: wkwkwkwkwkw, i am not carefull, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Correct your date and use `2000-12-12` instead of `0200-12-12`

and increase the size of `Gender` column as you are entering value more than 7 characters in length.

Answer (score 0):

Make **VARCHAR(20)** for **GENDER** column.